# What Original language used in writing the Scripture is the most accurate?

Tags: biblical-basis, life-of-jesus, church-history, bible

There are many translations used in writing the content of the Scripture. But can you tell us the most accurate language/translation?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your question title and question body aren't the same... It doesn't make sense to ask which source language is most accurate. And which translation is most accurate is very much debated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for what language each book of the Bible was originally written in, in order to avoid the interpretative influence of translators?

For 65 of the 66 books of the Protestant Bible the answer is quite straightforward:

- Old Testament: **Hebrew**...except for
- Ezra 4:8 to 6:18, 7:12-26; Daniel 2:4 to 7:28, plus a handful of words elsewhere: **Aramaic** ([source](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bd/aramaic?lang=eng))
- Mark through Revelation: **Greek**

--

**Matthew**

The Greek text is used in textual criticism and is the best attested in early manuscripts. However...

Every early Christian historian who wrote on the matter stated that the Gospel of Matthew was originally written in Hebrew, not Greek. Relevant testimony was given by Papias, Pantaneus, Irenaues, Origen, Epiphanius, Eusebius, Jerome, and others. [This site](https://hebrewgospel.com/Matthew%20Two%20Gospels%20Main%20Evidence.php) offers a review of the statements made by early church fathers on the matter.

Those rejecting this view must claim that the early historians were unanimously wrong. This is a tall order considering that Pantaneus claimed to have a copy of Matthew in Hebrew, and Origen was one of the greatest Hebrew scholars in Christian history.

A textual witness to a Hebrew original may survive: Shem Tob Matthew. It's a copy of the Gospel of Matthew in Hebrew that was written into a 14th century Jewish polemic against Christianity. For further discussion on this document and the possibility of a Hebrew original of the Gospel of Matthew, see my post [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/93522/51818).

---

<sup>In the interest of being thorough I should acknowledge there is ancient testimony that Mark was originally written in Latin and Hebrews was originally written in Hebrew. But this testimony is limited and is unsupported by surviving documentation. Further discussion [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/93522/51818).</sup>